# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide in Python when training regression models

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a LASSO and RIDGE model for my data and I am running into a RuntimeWarning that *I think* has to do with a division by zero. Unfortunately I am not sure why this is the case. I am filtering my features to exclude those with variance equal to zero, however this error still appears from time to time within the initial for loop. Because the error does not alway appear I believe it has something to do with how the data is split into the training and test sets.

`X` has roughly 900 columns (features) and 90 rows (samples) and `y` has 90 rows and 1 column.

```
start = time.time()
alphas  = 10**np.linspace(10,-2,100)*0.5
ridgecv = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5, normalize=True)
lassocv = LassoCV(alphas=None, cv=5, max_iter=100000, normalize=True, n_jobs=6, verbose=False)
for i in range(0, len(bin_info.index)):

    idx = int(bin_info.iloc[[i]].T.columns.values)
    y = chip.iloc[idx].T

    # split
    X_train, X_test , y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=None)

    # remove features with zero variance
    X_train = X_train.loc[:, X_train.var() > 0]
    X_test  = X_test[X_train.columns.values]

    # fit 
    ridgecv.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
    lassocv.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())        

    # predict
    r_predicted = ridgecv.predict(X_test)
    l_predicted = lassocv.predict(X_test)
```

Any insight as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The exact warning is posted below:

```
/Users/ss/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3184: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[None, :]
```

Comment: Need the data and complete code to duplicate the behaviour.